# How to render image from Flask-SQLAlchemy on page?

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to render image on my website but it's doesn't work (i see only corrupted file icon). Could You please tell me what i'm doing wrong ?

The way how I upload the image:

```
@app.route('/UploadImages')
def UploadImages():
    return render_template('UploadImages.html')


@app.route('/uploadImages', methods=['POST'])
def uploadImages():
    name = current_user.USERNAME
    file = request.files['inputFile']
    newFile=IMAGES(
        NAME=file.filename,
        USERNAME=name,
        DATA=file.read()
    )
    db.session.add(newFile)
    db.session.commit()

    return 'Saved ' + file.filename + 'to the database !'
```

Here is my db table:

```
class IMAGES(db.Model):
    ID = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    NAME = db.Column(db.String(300),unique=True)
    DATA = db.Column(db.BLOB)
    USERNAME = db.Column(db.String(15))
```

I'm sure that the file is upload correctly because when I use:

```
@app.route('/download')
def download():
    file_data = IMAGES.query.filter_by(USERNAME='test1').first()

    return send_file(BytesIO(file_data.DATA),
attachment_filename='test.jpg',as_attachment=True)
```

I get the image not corrupted.

How I try to render the file:

```
@app.route('/image')
def image():
    file_data = IMAGES.query.filter_by(USERNAME='test1').first()
    image = b64encode(file_data.DATA)
    return render_template('Image.html',data=list,image=image)
```

and on the website:

```
<img src="data:;b64encode,{{ image }}"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `<img>` data URI should be `data:;base64,{{ image }}` and not `data:;b64encode,{{ image }}`.

Comment: I use `img src="data:;base64,{{ image }}"/>` but still the same. I inspected the image object (Chrome F12)  [link](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AvdPsdAoxFQkg61laJUQcoewnz8x6g) i think the problem is in transformation (BLOB -> image)

Comment: I've just used `image = base64.b64encode(file_data.DATA).decode('ascii')` and it works :)

Comment: This worked for me too! Perhaps, you could add it as an answer, making it easier for everyone to read the solution. I will upvote it.

Comment: Has there been updates where this solution is outdated? I am able to convert it although the html side does not work for me

Answer (score 2):

As i have read this above the solution given by @Szymo n  is the appropriate one for this.

In your main route do these things`

```
@app.route('/image')
def image():
    file_data = IMAGES.query.filter_by(USERNAME='test1').first()
    image = base64.b64encode(file_data.DATA).decode('ascii')
    return 
render_template('Image.html',data=list,image=image)`
```

And in html file write the following code:

```
<img src="data:;base64,{{ image }}"/>
```